# MathJax not working in Angular5 Div with observable

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, angular5, mathjax

How can I make it so the elements nested within my div can be altered by MathJax to convert from TeX to HTML.

Currently I have this app.component.html:

```html
<p>
  When \(a \ne\) It works baby
</p>
<div class="topnav">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<div class="theoremsContainer">
  <ul>
    <div *ngFor="let theorem of bibleObservable | async">
      <ngb-alert type="info" [dismissible]="false">
        <h1>{{theorem.rule}}: {{theorem.name}}</h1>
        <p>{{theorem.eq}}</p>
      </ngb-alert>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

The paragraph tag at the top correctly formats but the theorems nested in the div with the ngFor tag are not properly displayed, instead only showing TeX. For reference this is my app.component.ts:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bible',
  templateUrl: './bible.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bible.component.scss']
})
export class BibleComponent implements OnInit {

  bibleObservable: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.bibleObservable = this.getRule('/theorems');
  }

  getRule(listPath): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.db.list(listPath).valueChanges();
  }

}
```

How do I make it so MathJax also alters elements nested in this div?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the correct subscribe to get those values? I mean, for each Observable.subscribe() ?

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to do this?

Comment: `this.getRule('theorems').subscribe()`

Comment: Why is this neccesarry?

Comment: BibleComponent.html:8 ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Comment: Probably you should not save bibleObservable: Observable<any[]>; as an Observable. Just `bible : any[]`. Then `this.getRule(''theorems).subscribe( (res) => { this.bible = res } )` Think about the Observables as a cute way to manage a JS promise.